# Request to the server does not pass

Tags: java, android, request, retrofit, response

I have some backend which adds new data in the database. Link for add new data looks like this:

```
...handler.php?type=add&comment=ads&idImage=2&idAuthor=3
```

And response:

```
{
    "success": true
}
```

And my inteface:

```
public interface CommentAddRequest
{
    @GET("handler.php")
    Observable<SimpleResponse> getResponse(@Query("type") String type,
                                           @Query("comment") String comment,
                                           @Query("idImage") Long idImage,
                                           @Query("idAuthor") Long idAuthor
    );
}

public class SimpleResponse
{
    public Boolean getSuccess()
    {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success)
    {
        this.success = success;
    }

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
}
```

I formirate requset like this:

```
    public static Observable<SimpleResponse> addComment(String comment, Long idImage, Long idAuthor)
    {
        String type = "add";
        CommentAddRequest service = ServiceGenerator.createService(CommentAddRequest.class);
        return service.getResponse(type, comment, idImage, idAuthor);
    }
}
```

I debug my code and everything is normal. Request is sends. But in DB doesn't add new data. Though through the browser it works normal. I don't have idea where i should looking up the error. Can you help me?

Comment: so do you get a success in response?

Comment: Do you have so code that actually interacts with the DB ?